# how can I move imported image in Python

Tags: python, pygame

so I was wondering if there was a way to import images(as sprites) in pygame and make them move like we can do with drawn polygons. Below I have given the code which I tried .

```
import pygame
from pygame import (
KEYDOWN,
QUIT,
K_ESCAPE,
K_UP,
K_DOWN,
K_LEFT,
K_RIGHT,
K_SPACE
)
x=30 ; y = 30
white =(255,255,255)
width = 720
height = 1280
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((height, width))
surface = pygame.Surface((640,360),pygame.SRCALPHA)
screen.fill(white)
image = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\spars\Downloads\a.jpg')
pygame.display.flip()
running = True
press = pygame.key.get_pressed() 
while running:
for event in pygame.event.get():
if event.type == KEYDOWN:
if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
running= False
if event.key == K_SPACE:
screen.blit(image, (0,0))
pygame.display.flip()
elif event.type == QUIT:
running = False
if press[K_UP]:
screen.blit(image,(x,y))
pygame.display.update()
y+=10
if press[K_DOWN]:
screen.blit(image,(x,y))
pygame.display.update()
y-=10
if press[K_LEFT]:
screen.blit(image,(x,y))
pygame.display.update()
x-=10
if press[K_RIGHT]:
screen.blit(image,(x,y))
pygame.display.update()
x=+10
```

I am sorry as it is my first time adding codes on stack overflow if the code is formatted wrong.
I tried another code to make it move(more like jump)

```
import pygame
from pygame import (
KEYDOWN,
QUIT,
K_ESCAPE,
K_UP,
K_DOWN,
K_LEFT,
K_RIGHT,
K_SPACE
)
white =(255,255,255)
width = 720
height = 1280
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((height, width))
surface = pygame.Surface((640,360),pygame.SRCALPHA)
screen.fill(white)
image = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\spars\Downloads\a.jpg')
pygame.display.flip()
running = True
press = pygame.key.get_pressed() 
while running:
for event in pygame.event.get():
if event.type == KEYDOWN:
if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
running= False
if event.key == K_SPACE:
for i in range (0,50):
screen.blit(image, (0,i))
i+=1
pygame.display.flip()
elif event.type == QUIT:
running = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Explanation

I have made some major changes to your code. I added `pygame.quit()` after the while loop so that the window will close when `running` is `False`. I moved all the keypress events (the events that are called when the arrow keys are pressed or when the space key is pressed or when the escape key is pressed) to inside the `if pygame.event == pygame.KEYDOWN` block. That way, when you press a key, the program will check which key was pressed. In the up arrow event, I switched `y += 10` to `y -= 10` because the smaller the `y` is, the higher the sprite is drawn. In the down arrow event, I switched `y -= 10` to `y += 10` due to the same reason. I removed the `screen.blit(image (x, y)` functions from each of the events. It is unnecessary to call the same function multiple times in the same loop. Instead, I called it once after checking for events. At the very end of the loop, I added `pygame.display.update()` so that the screen will get updated each frame. At the beginning of the while loop, before checking for events, I added `window.fill(white)` so that everything that was drawn in the previous frames will be cleared. Next, I added a boolean variable called `spacePressed` which I set to `False` before the while loop and set to `True` when the space key was pressed. Then, in the while loop, I checked if `spacePressed` is equal to `True`. If it is, the sprite will be drawn. Lastly, I indented your code.

## Code

```
import pygame

x=30 ; y = 30
white =(255,255,255)
width = 720
height = 1280
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((height, width))
image = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\spars\Downloads\a.jpg')
running = True
spacePressed = False
while running:
    screen.fill(white)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            press = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            if press[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
                running = False

            if press[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                spacePressed = True

            if press[pygame.K_UP]:
                y -= 10

            if press[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                y += 10

            if press[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                x -= 10

            if press[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                x += 10

    if spacePressed:
        screen.blit(image, (x, y))

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

If you have any questions, feel free to ask me.